# QT SqlQueryModel, TreeView and SortFilterProxyModel how to get selected row

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a TreeView that is feeded by a SortFilterProxyModel that is feeded by a SqlQueryModel.

Now I want to add double click event so that an edit dialog is loaded with data from the selected row and can be edited.

But all I get is a "random" row to be loaded, it's like the TreeView current index is wrong. My guess is that the SortFilterProxyModel is messing it up, but I have no clue on how to get the right index.

This is how I set my models:

```
proxyModel = new SortFilterProxyModel();

treeView = new QTreeView();
treeView->setModel(proxyModel);

sqlModel = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(sqlModel);
```

And this is my code that gets the wrong row:

```
QSqlRecord product = sqlModel->record(treeView->currentIndex().row());
```

I'm a newbie on QT but I've looked everywhere on the net and couldn't find an answer, so I'm hoping someone here can help me! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave the answer they gave me in another web:

> You need to take the view's currentIndex(), which is a model index for
>   the sorted/filter side of the proxy model, and use the proxy model's
>   QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource() function to obtain a
>   corresponding model index for the source model. Then you can use that
>   index (if valid) to address the SQL model directly.